# How to make background disappear with animation in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I have this code to show a subview in my app

```
if showContent {
            ZStack {
                ContentView(name: "", showAddWindow: false, title: $curLName)
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                          Button(action: {
                            withAnimation {
                                    self.showContent.toggle()
                            }
                          }) {
                            Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill").font(.title)
                            Spacer()
                          }.padding(.leading, 20)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding(.top,15)
            }
            .background(darkMode ? Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)) : Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)))
            .animation(.default)
            .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
        }
```

Foe some reason, the background disappears with no animation at all, while all other elements of the subview have the animation, and it looks terrible to say the least. How can I fix it?
UPD: Video of the issue: [Video](https://youtu.be/XEaYCrpoDps)

Same problem persists even on window which isn't drawn by a sub-view

```
if showAddWindow {
            VStack {
                Text("Добавить список")
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding(5)
                TextField("Введите название", text: $lName)
                    .padding(.horizontal,25)
                Divider()
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        if lName != "" {
                            allists.insert(element(name:lName),at:0)
                            lName=""
                            saveNamesList()
                        self.showAddWindow.toggle()
                        }}, label: {
                        Text("ОК")
                            .padding(.vertical,6)
                            .padding(.horizontal,56)
                })
                    Divider()
                    Button(action: {
                        lName=""
                        self.showAddWindow.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Отмена")
                            .padding(.vertical,6)
                            .padding(.horizontal,40)
                })
                }
            }
            .frame(width:300, height:140)
            .background(darkMode ? Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)) : Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)))
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:25,style: .continuous))
            .shadow(radius:15)
            .transition(AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .leading), removal: .move(edge:.trailing)))
            .animation(.default)
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the color to change only on dark mode/light mode changes:

From my experience programmatically changing color for dark mode/light mode doesnt work well in SwiftUI. You should instead declare your dark-mode-friendly colors in the assets folder and use those colors. You'll also get a little bit of a nice animation for free, when users change from light mode to dark mode.

There are other approaches as well, but i find this approach good enough.
Here's a useful post about how to define dynamic colors and more: https://medium.com/@drevathy/dark-theme-for-ios-13-in-swift-efc62ef6d16e

EDIT: regarding the transition not working, i found a solution in another stackoverflow question.
basically you need to apply a `.zIndex([A Sufficient Number Here])` at the end of your view, before you reach the end of the `if showContent {  }`.
something like:

```
if showContent {
            ZStack {
                ContentView(name: "", showAddWindow: false, title: $curLName)
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                          Button(action: {
                            withAnimation {
                                    self.showContent.toggle()
                            }
                          }) {
                            Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill").font(.title)
                            Spacer()
                          }.padding(.leading, 20)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding(.top,15)
            }
            .background(darkMode ? Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)) : Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)))
            .animation(.default)
            .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
            .zIndex(2) // <<------ Note this!
        }
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, doesn't show the transition

Comment: It looks like you kinda didn't understand the point. Changing from dark to white mode works flawlessly, but the problem is that when the sub-view is activated, animation plays for both the subview and the background, but when it's closed, background disappears immediately, and then the subview disappears with animation

Comment: Everything is working well on my side, but that could be due to the fact that you didn't add `ContentView` in the question and i had to remove `ContentView` from the codes to be able to test.

Comment: You still didn't get the problem... Changing between white and dark mode works perfectly and worked perfectly the way I implemented it. The only thing that doesn't work is that when I close the sub-view, background disappears immediately, without any transition

Comment: Your background IS your ContentView. I have 0 Idea how your ContentView looks like because you didn't include it in you question. I can't reproduce your problem without the ContentView. Update your question with a workable example of ContentView so me/others can test/reproduce.

Comment: I have a background behind ContentView, it's made with .background, and, for some reason, it disappears without any animation. And ContentView is just a view with a title and a ScrollView. I can show you the video with the problem if you want

Comment: Anything extra would benefit. Without ContentView everything works fine and the background dismisses and appears as i expect (goes to the side and comes back smoothly with animation, each time i toggle `showContent`). This makes me think contents of your `ContentView` are important so thats why i said i need the `ContentView`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The problem isn't with he ContentView, the same problem persists when I create an addition or removal window, which code I provided in the question

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
struct Main: View {
    @State var color: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello world")
            .padding()
            .onTapGesture { self.color.toggle() }
            .background(self.color ? Color.black : Color.white)
            .animation(.default)
   }
}
```

[image: Short gif showing how the code above works]

So I think that by replacing color literals with SwiftUI Color properties the problem will be solved.

(Xcode 12.4 playground)

Comment: Didn't work for me. For some reason it doesn't work with .transition, but I need it